# Como remover valores null, false e true de arquivo Json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Possuo um arquivo JSON com estes dados:

```
{
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "id_str": "92",
    "entities": {
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "urls": [],
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [0,8]
            }
        ]
    },
    "geo": null,
    "user": {
        "verified": false,
        "notifications": null,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "url": null,
        "id": 278,
        "default_profile": false,
        "lang": "pt",
        "location": null,
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false
    },
    "id": 92,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct",
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "text": "Esta \u00e9 a vdd",
    "truncated": false,
    "retweeted": false
}
```

Como posso excluir o par chave/valor que contém valor `null`, `false` e `true` deste arquivo usando Python?

Sabendo que esses valores que devem ser excluídos aparecem em várias partes do dicionário e quando tento fazer:

```
with open(arq_geral,'r') as f:
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    dados_tweet.append(tweet)


for tweet in dados_tweet:
    if tweet["geo"]:
        del tweet["geo"]
```

Ele não remove o 'geo', por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer uma função recursiva:

```
def filter_dict_by_value(dicionary, values):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dicionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            result[key] = filter_dict_by_value(value, values)
        elif value not in values:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

Percorre todos os pares chave/valor do dicionário; se o valor for outro dicionário, chama a função novamente para este valor; caso contrário, se o valor não estiver na lista `values` será mantido no dicionário final; se o valor estiver na lista, será ignorado.

O código ficaria algo como:

```
import json

with open("data.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

def filter_dict_by_value(dicionary, values):
    result = {}
    for key, value in dicionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            result[key] = filter_dict_by_value(value, values)
        elif value not in values:
            result[key] = value
    return result

print(filter_dict_by_value(data, [None, False, True]))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/N6v1/2)</sup>

Produzindo a saída:

```
{
    'id_str': '92', 
    'entities': {
        'user_mentions': [], 
        'symbols': [], 
        'urls': [], 
        'hashtags': [
            {
                'indices': [0, 8]
            }
        ]
     }, 
     'user': {
         'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'FFFFFF', 
         'id': 278, 
         'lang': 'pt', 
         'translator_type': 'none'
     }, 
     'id': 92, 
     'created_at': 'Tue Oct', 
     'text': 'Esta é a vdd'
}
```